# Force throwTo to block until an exception handler finishes

Tags: haskell, concurrency, exception, ghc

I'd like to be able to handle an async exception in thread `A` such that if another thread `B` calls `throwTo`, that call blocks until my handler in `A` has a chance to *finish*. As I understand it `throwTo` only blocks until the exception is "received".

I thought maybe some clever use of `uninterruptibleMask` might help me, but I'm stumped.

**EDIT**: I just noticed [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#g:3):

> The difference between using try and catch for recovery is that in
>   catch the handler is inside an implicit block (see "Asynchronous
>   Exceptions") which is important when catching asynchronous exceptions, ...

I thought that might be suggesting that `catch` would actually do what I'm looking for (I was using `onException`), but that doesn't seem to be the case. So as an additional question: what is meant by "the handler is inside an implicit `block`" here?

Comment: You could always make your own `throwTo`, but you probably already new that.